# How to kill spawned process in node.js

Tags: node.js, function, logic, spawn

I have a function that needs to kill the previous ffmpeg process before spawning a new one however I'm not sure how to do this because I will understandably get ffmpeg is not defined if I attempt the code below:

```
var ffmpeg_started = false;
function start_ffmpeg(file) {
  if (ffmpeg_started)
    ffmpeg.kill();
  var command =  [
               '-i', file,
               '-f', 'mpegts',
               '-codec:v', 'mpeg1video',
               'http://server.com/'
                ];
  }
  const ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', command);  
  ffmpeg_started = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy/simple solution is to just move the `ffmpeg` declaration into the parent scope. Then you could do away with the boolean flag and just check `ffmpeg`'s value to tell if it's still running. For example:

```
var ffmpeg;
function start_ffmpeg(file) {
  if (ffmpeg)
    ffmpeg.kill();
  ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', ...);
}
```

If you need to anything more complex than that, you might consider using a queue or similar to handle invocations of ffmpeg more elegantly.

Comment: ffmpeg needs to be a constant so this gives me an error since I can't make an assignment to a constant.

Comment: Why does it *need* to be a constant?

Comment: It seems to work with var instead of const - I'm not sure why all the examples use const. But so far it has worked. I will look into using a queue as well, thank you.